Converting CFSocket to NWConnection - Problem imported DER - SSL problems
So I have code using CFSocket and I wanted to see what it'd be like to use the newer NWConnection API.
So my CFSocket using the following to set up the SSL
Here I take the cert and the password I import the cert which is in PKCS12 format
   let err = SecPKCS12Import(
      data as NSData,
      [kSecImportExportPassphrase as String: password] as NSDictionary,
      &items
   )

I have limited understanding of SSL and all the formats but it seems like PKCS12 has both the private key and public key combined.
Later I create a properties dictionary with the following
   [
      kCFStreamSSLLevel as String: StreamSocketSecurityLevel.tlSv1 as NSObject,
      // validation is NOT necessary
      kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain as String: NSNumber(false) as NSObject,
      // this uses items![0][kSecImportItemIdentity as String] from the import function used earlier
      kCFStreamSSLCertificates as String: [secIdentity] as NSObject
   ]

So I set the TLS standard, tell it to NOT validate, and return the certificate in some format that was returned to us by the SecPKCS12Import function. This works without issue.
Alright now to NWConnection.
First I get the SecCertificate
   let certificateData = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path)).  
   let serverCertificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, certificateData as CFData)!

And now we create the parameters
private func createTLSParameters(queue: DispatchQueue, sslCertificates: [SecCertificate]) -> NWParameters {
        let options = NWProtocolTLS.Options()
        sec_protocol_options_set_min_tls_protocol_version(options.securityProtocolOptions, .TLSv12)
        sec_protocol_options_set_verify_block(options.securityProtocolOptions, { (secMetadata, secTrust, completeVerification) in
            let trust = sec_trust_copy_ref(secTrust).takeRetainedValue()

            // Set SSL policy with or without SSL hostname (SNI)
            let policy = SecPolicyCreateSSL(
                true,
                // dvttodo
                // self.host.debugDescription as CFString
                nil /* "ssl.hostname.com" as CFString DVTTODO add hostname maybe */
            )
            var result = SecTrustSetPolicies(trust, policy)
            guard result == errSecSuccess else {
                assertionFailure("☠️ SecTrustSetPolicies failed: \(result)")
                completeVerification(false)
                return
            }

            // Pin certificate.
            result = SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates(trust, sslCertificates as CFArray)
            guard result == errSecSuccess else {
                assertionFailure("☠️ SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates failed: \(result)")
                completeVerification(false)
                return
            }

            //use only the achor cert and trust all certs
            result = SecTrustSetAnchorCertificatesOnly(trust, true)
            guard result == errSecSuccess else {
                assertionFailure("☠️ SecTrustSetAnchorCertificatesOnly failed: \(result)")
                completeVerification(false)
                return
            }

            // Do NOT validate
//            // verify trust
//            var error: CFError?
//            if SecTrustEvaluateWithError(trust, &error) == false {
//                assertionFailure("☠️ SecTrustEvaluateWithError: \(String(describing: error))")
//                completeVerification(false)
//                return
//            }

            completeVerification(true)
        }, queue)

        return NWParameters(tls: options)
    }

Now I set the TLS version, and I dont validate, but I don't see a way to import the DER file with my password. And the DER file that I generated with openSSL only has the public key in it.
On the server a series of certs and keys were made.
# Create a client.p12 file for iOS clients.
openssl pkcs12 -export -in client_cert.pem -inkey client_key.pem -out client.p12 -passout pass:$jksPassword >>/tmp/gen_certs.log 2>&1

# Provide the client private key and certificate in DER format as well.
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in client-p8key.pem -outform der -out client-pkey.der >>/tmp/gen_certs.log 2>&1
openssl x509 -in client_cert.pem -outform der -out client-cert.der >>/tmp/gen_certs.log 2>&1

It seems like I'm missing a way to import the private key onto my system.
When I connect I get the following error:
tcp_input [C1:2] flags=[R.] seq=2757644646, ack=191466905, win=15 state=ESTABLISHED rcv_nxt=2757644646, snd_una=191466905
boringssl_context_handle_fatal_alert(2072) [C1:1][0x108b12d40] read alert, level: fatal, description: handshake failure
nw_read_request_report [C1] Receive failed with error "handshake failure"
boringssl_session_handshake_incomplete(210) [C1:1][0x108b12d40] SSL library error
boringssl_session_handshake_error_print(44) [C1:1][0x108b12d40] Error: 4440861376:error:10000410:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE:/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/boringssl/ssl/tls_record.cc:592:SSL alert number 40
nw_protocol_boringssl_handshake_negotiate_proceed(779) [C1:1][0x108b12d40] handshake failed at state 12288: not completed

